# Designing graph using Dygraphs gives a weird error message

Tags: javascript, .net, vb.net, graph, dygraphs

I am trying to design a graph using [Dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com/) library with the following simple code. If I hard-code the values inside the designRawGraphs() function, then the graph is appeared properly. But, if I try to get the values from code behind to client side using a `hidden` div (which is a typical and very common process in .NET) I am getting nothing in the graph.

**Client Side Code**

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/dygraph-combined.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/dygraph-extra.js"></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updpanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>

<div>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click"></asp:Button>
<div class="graphdiv" id="graphdiv" style="width:90%; margin: 0 auto;">      </div>
<div id="hiddenroi1" style="display: none;"><%= sDataForROI1Graph %></div>
<script>
designRawGraphs(); 
   function designRawGraphs()
   {    
       var hiddendata = document.getElementById("hiddenroi1").innerHTML;
       var g1 = new Dygraph(
                document.getElementById("graphdiv"),
                  [   hiddendata
                       //[0, 53.67, 23.43]
                       //, [0.653, 57.69, 24.43]
                       //, [0.986, 70.67, 22.43]
                  ]
                );

    }
 </script>
 </div> 
 </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
 </form>
 </body>
```

**Back End Code**

```
Public sDataForROI1Graph As String = "[ , ]"

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    sDataForROI1Graph = "[0, 53.67, 23.43], [0.653, 57.69, 24.43], [0.986, 70.67, 22.43]"
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType, "testScript", "designRawGraphs();", True)
End Sub
```

Also I am getting the following weird message for the `hiddendata` variable:

> error BC30451: 'hiddendata' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.